# Compare html entities written with ASP to html entities read by JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, entities

I have a few different html strings written to the DOM via ASP.NET and stored in sessions also. These strings contain html entities like "`&nbsp;`" and "`&minus;`".

I use .html() to get the html printed by the asp, then I POST the html in the background using AJAX to another asp document where I try to compare the html in the session to the html the JS grabbed after it was written.

My problem is that when they are compared, the string from the JS will show as "- blah" and the asp session obviously shows as "`&minus;&nbsp;blah`". How can I get either the JS to match the asp or the other way around?

I've tried using Server.HTMLEncode(session("name")) which gets most the strings to match, but changes the '`&`' on '`&minus;`' to '`&amp;minus;`'.

Any help would be greatly appreiciated! Thanks in advance.

Here’s a fiddle to show the code. JS fiddle doesn't run asp.
http://jsfiddle.net/JnKaT/3/

Jquery

```
$('#submit').click(function(st) {       

    $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(rc) {
        var userAns =  $(this).parent().next('td').html();

        console.log(userAns);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            data: userAns,
            url: "/beta/includes/answerCheck.asp",
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg+" ");
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);                
            }
        });

    });

    return false;
    st.preventDefault();
});​
```

ASP

```
<!-- creating dynamic session name for html string -->
<%
for j = 1 to itemCount
sessionName = "correctAns"&(j)
session(sessionName) = session("d1")

response.write("<div class='qans'>"&session(sessionName)&"</div>")

next
%>


<!-- asp used by AJAX to compare the session to the js string -->


<%
userAns = request.form()


    corSessionName = "correctAns"&(qn)
    userSessionName = "userAns"&(qn)

        if userAns = session(corSessionName) then
            response.write("correct! ")

            response.write("ASP:"&session(corSessionName))
            response.write(" ,user:"&userAns)
        end if

        if userAns <> session(corSessionName) then 
            session(userSessionName) = userAns

            response.write("incorrect :( ")

            response.write("ASP:"&session(corSessionName))
            response.write(" ,user:"&userAns)
        end if  
%>
```

Button

```
<button id="submit" name="Check my answers!!" align="left">Check my answers!</button>​
```

Comment: you have a typo in the ajax url

Comment: I don't think so. I get all the responses back in the console log on the live page, I just made some minor edits to make it easier to post.
The responses in the console show "ASP: &minus;blah ,User: -blah"

Comment: When HTML strings are parsed into the DOM, HTML entities are replaced by their corresponding characters. HTML entities do not exist in the DOM, and when serializing the DOM via `.html()` you will not encounter them.

Comment: I see.. Is there perhaps a way to serialize the html in the asp session?

Comment: you never closed the string starting in the ajax url request with doble quotes, just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sime Vidas said I can not get the HTML Entities back from the DOM so to solve my issue I decoded the html string in the asp session to get it to match the html on the DOM

```
Dim I
tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&quot;", Chr(34))
tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&nbsp;", " ")

For I = 1 to 255
    tempAns = Replace(tempAns, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
Next

session(sessionName) = tempAns
```